Make animation using Python but give me an error, animation can't appear
I want to plot animation of y=omega*x^2, which omega is -3 into 3 with step size 0.25, x from -4 into 4 with step size 0.001. I'm new studying plot animation in Python.
I try to make a code but give me an error as follows and no animation appear.
UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you have outputted the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.

Process finished with exit code 0

This is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig = plt.figure()
axis = plt.axes(xlim=(-4, 4), ylim=(-40, 40))
line, = axis.plot([], [], lw=3)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(omega):
    x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 8000)
    y = omega*x**2
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

I don't know what the mistake of the code. How to fix the code such that the animation can appear? Thanks for your help.

The error message suggests two ways to fix the problem, have you tried them?

If it’s in a notebook, ply.show() isn’t necessary, and they’re already doing anim = …

I have tried, and it works.

As the error message you've provided says, you just need to include plt.show() at the very end of your code, and you will see the animation.
